# Stripe.Net json parsing error on create.refund

Tags: asp.net

Hi i have code for a webhook that refuneds a customer, testing api works fine in test mode, but while still in tested mode i actually refund a dummy transction and i get this error

Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path 'request', line 111, position 14.

Appreciate any help : ) thanks you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to the difference in Api version between Stripe server and my applications.